# cannot paint rectangles correctly with wxPython during dragging

Tags: wxpython

I'm new to wxPython and I want to make a reusable `Panel` with these features:

- Set a background (done)
- Draw rectangles (done)
- Move rectangles (done with a bug)

When I move the rectangle with the mouse what I see on the windows is this:

1. When I press the mouse button the rectangle disappear (it should remain visible)
2. When I start drag the rectangle another one is painted in the original position (not ok), and another is following the mouse (correct behaviour)
3. When I release the mouse button there is no problem and the rectangle is painted only where the user want

## Code Resume

This is a brief explaination of the code:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
```

In the paint method I repaint all, the background and the rectangles

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_mouse_down)
```

In the mouse down handler if the mouse is hover a rectangle, that rectangle is removed temporarily and than the Panel is forced to repaint

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.on_mouse_up)
```

When the mouse button is released and we are in drag mode, the rectangle selected is reinserted in the list and than the Panel is forced to repaint

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_mouse_motion)
```

When the mouse is moving and we are in drag mode, the rectangle selected is painted in an overlay object

## Full code

```
from mouse_tracker import MouseTracker
import wx
from rect import Rect
from enum import Enum


class TrackMode(Enum):
    NONE = 0
    DRAWING = 1
    MOVING = 2


class DrawPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):

        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.bitmap = None
        self.rectangles = []
        self.track_mode = TrackMode.NONE

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_mouse_down)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.on_mouse_up)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_mouse_motion)

    def on_mouse_down(self, event):
        x = event.Position.x
        y = event.Position.y
        self.tracker = MouseTracker(x, y)

        hover_rects = (r for r in self.rectangles[::-1] if r.contains(x, y))
        self.moving_rect = next(hover_rects, None)

        self.tmp_dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        self.overlay = wx.Overlay()
        self.overlay_dc = wx.DCOverlay(self.overlay, self.tmp_dc)

        if self.moving_rect:
            self.track_mode = TrackMode.MOVING
            self.rectangles.remove(self.moving_rect)
            self.Parent.Refresh()
        else:
            self.track_mode = TrackMode.DRAWING
    

    def on_mouse_motion(self, event):
        if self.track_mode is TrackMode.NONE:
            return

        x = event.Position.x
        y = event.Position.y
        self.tracker.set_position(x, y)

        if self.track_mode is TrackMode.DRAWING:
            self.overlay_dc.Clear()
            x, y, w, h = self.tracker.get_rect()
            self.tmp_dc.DrawRectangle(x, y, w, h)
        elif self.track_mode is TrackMode.MOVING:
            self.overlay_dc.Clear()
            dx, dy = self.tracker.get_delta()
            x, y, w, h = self.moving_rect
            self.tmp_dc.DrawRectangle(x + dx, y + dy, w, h)

    def on_mouse_up(self, event):

        if self.track_mode is TrackMode.DRAWING:
            self.add_rect(self.tracker.get_rect())
        elif self.track_mode is TrackMode.MOVING:
            dx, dy = self.tracker.get_delta()
            self.moving_rect.move(dx, dy)
            self.add_rect(self.moving_rect)
            self.Parent.Refresh()

        self.tracker = None
        self.track_mode = TrackMode.NONE
        del self.tmp_dc, self.overlay, self.overlay_dc

    def on_paint(self, event):
        self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self)

        if self.bitmap:
            memory_dc = wx.MemoryDC(self.bitmap)
            w, h = self.bitmap.GetSize()
            self.dc.Blit(0, 0, w, h, memory_dc, 0, 0)
            del memory_dc

        for rect in self.rectangles:
            x, y, w, h = rect
            self.dc.DrawRectangle(x, y, w, h)

        del self.dc

    def set_background(self, bitmap):
        self.bitmap = bitmap

    def add_rect(self, rect):
        self.rectangles.append(rect)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    example = wx.Frame(None)
    panel = DrawPanel(example)
    bitmap = wx.Bitmap('screenshot.png')
    panel.set_background(bitmap)
    example.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
from rect import Rect


class MouseTracker:

    def __init__(self, x, y) -> None:
        self.start = (x, y)
        self.end = (x, y)

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.end = (x, y)

    def get_delta(self):
        dx = self.end[0] - self.start[0]
        dy = self.end[1] - self.start[1]

        return dx, dy

    def get_rect(self):
        rect = Rect()
        rect.set_points(
            self.start[0],
            self.start[1],
            self.end[0],
            self.end[1])

        return rect
```

```
from core import between


class Rect:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.w = None
        self.h = None

    def set_points(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        self.x = min(x0, x1)
        self.y = min(y0, y1)
        self.w = abs(x0 - x1)
        self.h = abs(y0 - y1)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y
        yield self.w
        yield self.h

    def contains(self, x, y):
        test_x = between(x, self.x, self.get_right())
        test_y = between(y, self.y, self.get_bottom())
        return test_x and test_y

    def get_bottom(self):
        return self.y + self.h

    def get_right(self):
        return self.x + self.w

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
```

```
def between(x, start, end):
    return x >= start and x <= end
```

## My problem

During the dragging operation there are 2 rectangles, one moving and one in the original position. The rectangle in the original position should not be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one serious problem there, and I do not think it makes sense to continue before we fix it. All the drawing must occur in the on_paint handler.  You are drawing your rects from the list, but the rect currently being drawn or dragged is never drawn. These operations with overlay you do in on_motion do not do anything.

I suggest that you check if there is any rect being drawn or dragged in the on_paint method, and *paint the update* there.

The screen is updated only when needed, so you must call self.Refresh() in every mouse up/down/motion. No need to call self.Parent.Refresh().

Also, I recommend against using del in this way. It does not really do anything with the object behind that variable, and for me to see it like this, it is rather confusing. I am asking myself: what is the reason for calling del here?

Comment: Some tutorials use ```del``` while others doesn't. But I will stop using it in this way. Thanks for your suggestions because I'am confused about the usage of wxPython.